# Mediaplayer doesn't set volumes for individual channel

Tags: java, android, volume

I am trying to use mediaplayer to create 3d audio locating for my game.

There is a weird problem however. When I adjust volumes for two channels individualy, it works. However sometimes some sound files doesn't play correctly.

Sound set for left channel only (1f, 0f) comes from both speakers. Then, if I set the volume, such, to mute left channel: 
`sound.setVolume(0f, 1f);`
then no sound comes.

If I set setVolume(1f,0f) then sound comes from both speakers.(Remember not for all sound files. Some sounds works as intended).

Why would I experience this setVolume misbehaviour?

```
sound = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.soundfile);
sound.start();
sound.setVolume(volumeLeft, volumeRight);
```